# Using dried cranberries instead of chocolate chips in cookies

Tags: chocolate, cookies, gluten-free, cranberries

Can I use dried cranberries instead of chocolate chips in my GF cookies?  Will it work the same?
If so, should I correct the sugar amount in the recipe?
Thanks

Comment: If someone's answer helped you, please upvote the answer and accept it so other users with the same problem are helped as well.

Answer (score 9):

Of course it won't be the same, it will be different. If the cranberries are sweetened, which dried cranberries often are, then just a straight substitution should work. The cookies will be a bit tarter, but should be just as delicious.

If the dried cranberries are unsweetened, then it probably does make sense to add a bit of sugar. You can do that by adding perhaps 1/8 more to the cookie, or you can glaze the cookies with a powdered sugar/water glaze.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Generally, whatever mix-ins you add to a cookie can be traded out for other things. You can even use half as many chips **and** add half as many cranberries if you like. Honestly, you can probably increase the percentage of mix-ins by half without doing damage to the final product, so if the recipe calls for 1 cup chips, you could add 3/4 cup each chips and cranberries.

Changing the amount of sugar, if you like the current sweetness, probably isn't necessary. It's difficult to predict because there's different cranberries (some sweetened, others not) and different chocolate chips (milk, dark, white, etc). You are also more likely to change the final cookie consistency, which will effect how much the dough spreads.

Comment: The amount by which mix-ins can be *increased* is greatly dependent on the amount which was called for in the original recipe. How much to use and what to use are, generally, personal choices. The absolute amount depends on the consistency of the dough, type of mix-in, etc. Mix-ins are something that you can experiment with. If you don't get quite the result you desire, you can just make another batch/experiment. If you are wanting to experiment with more combinations you can split the base dough into multiple parts and put in quantities of the mix-ins proportional to the split.

Comment: Good point! I make what I call "kitchen sink" oatmeal cookies and I nearly double the amount of mix ins. The recipe calls for chocolate chips only and I use mini chocolate chips, pecans, and currants. :)